# Distribute C++ binaries across linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, binaryfiles

I would like to distribute C++ binary that is created by using `Eclipse ++ IDE`, with the following settings:

```
Cross GCC Compiler: gcc -std=c++17 
Cross G++ Compiler: g++ -std=c++17
Tool Chain settings:
Cross GCC Compiler
Cross G++ Compiler
Cross GCC Linker
Cross G++ Linker
Cross GCC Archiver
Cross GCC Assembler
```

I am compiling with `boost::serilization` and have connect that in `Linker`. The binary is created on `Ubuntu 16.04`. I tried to run the binary on `Ubuntu 14.04`, and it give the error:

> > error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I have also installed `libboost` on the system by using

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-program-options-dev
```

But, it gives me the same error.

I think with the above `Eclipse IDE` setting, it should work in most of the `Linux platforms`. Is my presumption of its working on most of the `Linux` platforms wrong??.

Comment: What version of boost do you have on the target machine?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist `1.54.0` , error says it needs `1.58.0` ??

Comment: There you go... that's your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your program you link it with specific versions of the shared libraries. On older releases of e.g. Ubuntu those newer versions of the libraries doesn't exist.

If you want to copy the executable between different systems you need to link *statically*. That means all libraries are linked *into* the executable so it doesn't rely on shared libraries. It will make the executable bigger of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With that setting, is it supposed to work for all the `Linux` platforms

Comment: @AwaitedOne Well you still have to account for 32- and 64-bit platforms, which are different. And really old systems might have compatibility problems as well. But if you keep it within systems created the last 5 years or so it should not be a big problem (not counting the 32/64 bit thing).